# How to make multiplication in octave?

Tags: octave

I need to multiply some values bys using this line of code:

```
  % Apply hypothetical keys 
  tmp = bitxor( Y_i*ones(1,length(K)) , ones(length(Y_i),1)*K );
```

The error that I found is:

```
error: binary operator `*' not implemented for `int32 matrix' by `matrix' operations
error: evaluating binary operator `*' near line 49, column 17
error: evaluating argument list element number 1
error: evaluating assignment expression near line 49, column 7
```

Comment: The documentation isn't much help on this, but it seems that multiplying integer matrices is not supported by Octave. Have you tried casting `Y_i` as a double (at least temporarily)?

Comment: what size and type are Y_i and K ? Pleaseadd some code which defines example values for Y_i and K